# compare sharepoint with java world

Tags: sharepoint, jakarta-ee

I am a good java web developer having knowledge of numbers of technical issues in java industry.

I heard lot about SharePoint. I don't able to understand it because I don't have idea of workings in Microsoft world.

Can someone tell about SharePoint by taking a scenario from java world.

Comment: Did you try anything, e.g. having a look at Microsoft documentation online?

Comment: I search about it and got to know that Sharepoint acts a central repository for managing multiples websites. How does it differ from Mircosoft Visual Studio Software ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Central repository for what? Not really. No offence but you really need to do a bit more reading first. Try

- [What is Sharepoint](http://www.whatissharepoint.co.uk/)
- [Microsoft SharePoint - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint)
- [SharePoint product information page](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/pages/default.aspx)

> Can someone tell about SharePoint by taking a scenario from java world.

There isn't a direct correlation to Java. SharePoint is an application, Java is a programming language. It's like asking someone to describe Microsoft Excel in terms of the PHP world - doesn't really make sense as a question.

However, [Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) is an OSS project is **similar** to SharePoint and written in Java.

> How does it differ from Mircosoft Visual Studio Software

VisualStudio is an Integrated Development Environment (IDE), like Eclipse.